# Meteor._wrapAsync has been renamed to Meteor.wrapAsync undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have been getting the warning on meteor server start-up. `Meteor._wrapAsync has been renamed to Meteor.wrapAsync undefined`. Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just to let you know that the previously undocumented API `Meteor._wrapAsync` has been renamed to `Meteor.wrapAsync` and officially documented : http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_wrapasync

If you are not using directly this function in your own code, chances are that packages you are using call `Meteor._wrapAsync` themselves, if these packages are actively maintained, authors will fix them sooner or later.

Anyway, this is just a warning that won't impact your application, you shouldn't be alarmed because it's not going to break anything.

Comment: If you don't use it directly, this message could also pop up, because it has been used in an external package.

Comment: OK. And how do I find out which package is causing the error?

Comment: Well, you could start by removing all of your packages and readding them one by one to try isolating the faulty package.

Comment: @obiwahn You can pick out some of the packages which looks not so well maintained and search for the old function on GitHub. You may even want to make a revision and do a pull request.

Comment: Hm. That is a lot of work. I use around 25+ packages :-(

Answer (score 5):

As of writing (8 March 2015) the package that is causing this is almost certainly CollectionFS. I use `cfs:gridfs` as the store, so it's out of that or `cfs:standard-packages`.

`cfs:gridfs` also has a warning against deployment because it's not production ready... Perhaps this is one of the issues and I hope the package gets some love soon or else I'll have to jump in LOL.

Answer (score 1):

I am voting for cfs:standard-packages as the culprit, or maybe both of them, since the message occurs with either cfs.gridfs installed, or cfs:filesystem installed.